# Strange behavior between `std::make_unique` and `std::unique_ptr` with forward declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, shared-memory, unique-ptr

`std::make_unique<T>` needs `C++ 17` feature.It's a pity that I have to use `C++11`. When I am porting the code snippet to `C++11`, I found a strange thing.

The [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/Wo1TMz86f) which uses `make_unique` works well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
 
struct View;

struct Database : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Database>
{
    static std::shared_ptr<Database> Create(){ return std::shared_ptr<Database>(new Database());}

    std::unique_ptr<View> GetView() { return std::make_unique<View>(shared_from_this()); } //works well

    ~Database() {std::cout << "Database is destoryed" << std::endl;}
private:
        Database(){};
};

struct View
{
    std::shared_ptr<Database> db;
    View(std::shared_ptr<Database> db) : db(std::move(db)) {}
    ~View() {std::cout << "View is destoryed" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<View> view;
    {
        auto db{Database::Create()} ;
        view = db->GetView();
    }
}
```

whereas the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/P4vb57Gxn) below does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
 
struct View;

struct Database : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Database>
{
    static std::shared_ptr<Database> Create(){ return std::shared_ptr<Database>(new Database());}

    std::unique_ptr<View> GetView() { return std::unique_ptr<View>(new View(shared_from_this())); }  //here is the modification
    ~Database() {std::cout << "Database is destoryed" << std::endl;}
private:
        Database(){};
};

struct View
{
    std::shared_ptr<Database> db;
    View(std::shared_ptr<Database> db) : db(std::move(db)) {}
    ~View() {std::cout << "View is destoryed" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<View> view;
    {
        auto db{Database::Create()} ;
        view = db->GetView();
    }
}
```

Here is what the complier complains:

```
<source>: In member function 'std::unique_ptr<View> Database::GetView()':
<source>:10:95: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct View'
   10 |     std::unique_ptr<View> GetView() { return std::unique_ptr<View>(new View(shared_from_this())); }  //here is the modification
      |                                                                                               ^
<source>:4:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct View'
    4 | struct View;
      |        ^~~~
```

After I did some modification for the second code snippet,[this one works](https://godbolt.org/z/EPbn1oTzz):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Database;
 
struct View
{
    std::shared_ptr<Database> db;
    View(std::shared_ptr<Database> db) : db(std::move(db)) {}
    ~View() {std::cout << "View is destoryed" << std::endl;}
};

struct Database : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Database>
{
    static std::shared_ptr<Database> Create(){ return std::shared_ptr<Database>(new Database());}
    #if 0
    std::unique_ptr<View> GetView() { return std::make_unique<View>(shared_from_this()); } //works well
    #else
    std::unique_ptr<View> GetView() { return std::unique_ptr<View>(new View(shared_from_this())); }
    #endif
    ~Database() {std::cout << "Database is destoryed" << std::endl;}
private:
        Database(){};
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<View> view;
    {
        auto db{Database::Create()} ;
        view = db->GetView();
    }
}
```

**Why** `std::make_unique<View>(shared_from_this())` works even if there is only a forward delaration for `View` before `Database`'s definition, whereas the compiler complains about `std::unique_ptr<View>(new View(shared_from_this())` under the same condition?

Comment: How would that make sense in 1st place?

Comment: So you would like to create a `unique_ptr` from a `shared_ptr` as a view? It makes no sense.. I think you want a `weak_ptr`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, just after I posted this post, I realise there is sth wrong. See the session named `Updated`.

Comment: @John Just think about it. You have a `shared_ptr`, and who knows how many `shared_ptr`s are sharing that object. From one of them you will create a VIEW! as a `unique_ptr`. When the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, your original object will be destroyed, making crap from ALL the `shared_ptr`s. And at this point you screwed up. You need a `weak_ptr`!!!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Please wait for a moment. :) I hope you would not close it.

Comment: ***When the unique_ptr goes out of scope, your original object will be destroyed, making crap from ALL the shared_ptrs. And at this point you screwed up. You need a weak_ptr!!!***? When the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope,  if there the `shared_ptr` is still used by somewhere, the `shared_ptr` would not be destroyed, otherwise the `shared_ptr`  would be destroyed after the last user said `unique_ptr` went out of scope. I can't see any problem yet. Could you please explain that in simple words?

Comment: @John Okay now I see you added the `View` definition which was missing before. In this case any `unique_ptr` is pointles. You can return `View` simply by value if this is all the payload in it...

Comment: @John All you need is this: https://godbolt.org/z/1rT6zYKa5  It'll be also faster since you save a useless indirection

Comment: @John one question per question here please! You should be acknowledged enough about the rules.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The former question is meaningless now. Do you mean I should create a new other than modifying the old post and talk about it here? How to reversion this post?

Comment: @simre  " Okay now I see you added the View definition which was missing before" This is related to my second qusetion. I have updated the question right now.

Comment: @John I updated my answer to match the new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `std::make_unique<View>(shared_from_this())` works even if there is only a forward delaration for `View` before `Database`'s definition, whereas the compiler complains about `std::unique_ptr<View>(new View(shared_from_this())` under the same condition?

Consider this simplified example:

```
#include <memory>

struct foo;

std::unique_ptr<foo> make_foo_1() { return std::make_unique<foo>(); }       // OK
std::unique_ptr<foo> make_foo_2() { return std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo); } // ERROR

struct foo {};
```

In `make_foo_1`, `std::unique_ptr<foo>` is made a [dependent type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) in `make_unique<foo>` which means that it'll postpone binding to `unique_ptr<foo>`.

But *"Non-dependent names are looked up and bound **at the point of template definition**"* (i.e., the definition of `std::unique_ptr<foo>`) which means that, in `make_foo_2`, the definition of `foo` must have already been seen by the compiler or else it'll complain about `foo` being an incomplete type.

Comment: In your given example, in `make_foo_1` in particular how is `foo` a dependent type? It does not depend on any template parameter. And also in case of `make_foo__2` how does the same `foo` became `nondependent`? I mean afaik `foo` is nondependent in both cases. Or did i miss something obvious.

Comment: @AnoopRana I got that from _"types and expressions may depend on types of type template parameters"_ and _"the lookup of a dependent name used in a template is postponed until the template arguments are known"_. Perhaps it'd be better to say that `unique_ptr<foo>` is made a dependent type? I'm a bit unsure about the proper terminology there, I've seen both variants used.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `foo` cannot be called a dependent type in any way in the particular example that you gave. As you suggested `unique_ptr<foo> ` would be more accurate/close to the right terminology(to which the standard adhere). Maybe i will drop an answer later with exact terminology used in the standard and some additional explanation.  For the time being, saying `foo` is dependent is not correct afaik.

Comment: @AnoopRana Ok, I changed to `unique_ptr<foo>`, thanks!

Comment: @AnoopRana Perhaps I'll finally remember which one it is that is called "the dependent type" after this :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you have `std::make_unique<View>(shared_from_this())`, the compiler needs to instantiate the specialization of the function template `template<class T, class... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> std::make_unique(Args&&...);` with `T = View, Args = {<empty>}`. This happens at a "point of instantiation" of the specialization. There is one where it is used (right when you call `make_unique`), and also one at the end of the translation unit. Your compiler happens to instantiate it at the the end of the TU (as most compilers do), so it happens to "work", but it's actually ill-formed (since the compiler could have instantiated when it was used and it would have failed).

The reason `std::unique_ptr<View>(new View(shared_from_this()))` doesn't work is because the error is with the expression `new View(shared_from_this())`. There is no template function or point of instantiation to deal with, so the compiler has to complain immediately that `View` is incomplete, as expected.

The solution is to delay the definition of the function until `View` is complete:

```cpp
struct View;

struct Database : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Database>
{
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<View> GetView();
    // ...
};

struct View
{
    // ...
};


inline std::unique_ptr<View> Database::GetView()
{
    // View is complete here, OK
    return std::unique_ptr<View>(new View(shared_from_this()));
}
```